# how to kill opened apps using batchfile?

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to close opened app by running a batchfile code . My current code does not work and just freezes all black.

Code

```
@echo off
echo closing all programs...
taskkill /f /t /im explorer.exe
explorer.exe
```

Comment: Are you really trying to close `explorer.exe`? What makes you think that doing so will close all programs? or, What do you mean by all programs? What do you think the `/F` option does? and, Why are you using it?

Comment: Want I want is to close any opened apps

Comment: If you restart explorer.exe, depending on your computer's specs, it makes sense that it's going to freeze up for a bit. You're killing an important system process, and it's going to take some time to restart. You can't really use Windows without it. And if you kill explorer.exe, it's not going to also kill all other programs. It's only going to restart explorer.exe.

Comment: Personally, I would not interchange the terms 'app' and 'program'. For me an app would generally be the stuff you download from the Windows Store, _(if so inclined)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` should work oh and you should do `pause` or `pause >nul` at the end of the script else your program won't start also `explorer.exe` at the end of your script is not needed.